# Is there a way to mutate and create many new variables with one line of code?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have something like:

```
df<-data.frame(group=c(1, 1, 1, 1,1,2, 2, 2, 2), 
               date=c("2000-01-01 11:00:00", "2000-01-03 11:00:00", "2000-01-04 11:20:00", "2000-01-04 14:20:00", "2000-01-05 11:40:00", "2000-01-09 12:20:00", "2000-01-09 13:20:00", "2000-01-10 12:20:00", "2000-01-12 16:20:00"))
```

```
  group                date
1     1 2000-01-01 11:00:00
2     1 2000-01-03 11:00:00
3     1 2000-01-04 11:20:00
4     1 2000-01-04 14:20:00
5     1 2000-01-05 11:40:00
6     2 2000-01-09 12:20:00
7     2 2000-01-09 13:20:00
8     2 2000-01-10 12:20:00
9     2 2000-01-12 16:20:00
```

I'd like to make many columns indicating 24 hours after the date, 48 hours, etc. (for instance):

```
df%>%mutate(first=date+86400, second=date+172800, third=date+259200)
```

etc. etc. where I'm adding a day in seconds, but this is very time consuming (if I want hundreds of columns). I'm assuming there's a way to do this iteratively.

Thanks,

Comment: You can do `df[c('first', 'second', 'third')] <- lapply(1:3, function(x) as.POSIXct(df$date) + 86400 * x)` or with `tidyverse` `map(1:3, ~ as.POSIXct(df$date) + 86400 * .x) %>% bind_cols(df, .)`

Comment: If the column names are already created as a vector, then it is easier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we can make use of the `english` package, the column names can be generated while the values are generated with `lapply`

```
library(english)
df$date <- as.POSIXct(df$date)
df[as.character(ordinal(1:3))] <- lapply(1:3, function(x) df$date + 86400 * x)
```

It can be done in a single line of code with `as.POSIXct` conversion in the loop, but we would be unnecessarily doing conversion multiple times (Not all one-liners are efficient)

---

Or with `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map_dfc(1:3, ~ tibble(!! as.character(ordinal(.x)) := df$date + 86400 * .x)) %>%
   bind_cols(df, .)
# group                date               first              second               third
#1     1 2000-01-01 11:00:00 2000-01-02 11:00:00 2000-01-03 11:00:00 2000-01-04 11:00:00
#2     1 2000-01-03 11:00:00 2000-01-04 11:00:00 2000-01-05 11:00:00 2000-01-06 11:00:00
#3     1 2000-01-04 11:20:00 2000-01-05 11:20:00 2000-01-06 11:20:00 2000-01-07 11:20:00
#4     1 2000-01-04 14:20:00 2000-01-05 14:20:00 2000-01-06 14:20:00 2000-01-07 14:20:00
#5     1 2000-01-05 11:40:00 2000-01-06 11:40:00 2000-01-07 11:40:00 2000-01-08 11:40:00
#6     2 2000-01-09 12:20:00 2000-01-10 12:20:00 2000-01-11 12:20:00 2000-01-12 12:20:00
#7     2 2000-01-09 13:20:00 2000-01-10 13:20:00 2000-01-11 13:20:00 2000-01-12 13:20:00
#8     2 2000-01-10 12:20:00 2000-01-11 12:20:00 2000-01-12 12:20:00 2000-01-13 12:20:00
#9     2 2000-01-12 16:20:00 2000-01-13 16:20:00 2000-01-14 16:20:00 2000-01-15 16:20:00
```

Comment: I get "no applicable method for 'ordinal' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

Comment: @biostatguy12 I am not able to reproduce that issue though

Comment: @biostatguy12 I used `packageVersion('purrr')
[1] ‘0.3.2’
> packageVersion('dplyr')
[1] ‘0.8.3’
> packageVersion('english')
[1] ‘1.2.4’` on `R 3.6.2`

Comment: Ah maybe my purrr is not up to date, my R is 3.4.2. As always thanks for your help @akrun

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility involving `dplyr` and `purrr` could be:

```
map(86400*1:3, ~ df %>%
     transmute(!!paste(.x/3600, "hours", sep = "_") := as.POSIXct(date) + .x)) %>%
 bind_cols(df, .)

  group                date            24_hours            48_hours            72_hours
1     1 2000-01-01 11:00:00 2000-01-02 11:00:00 2000-01-03 11:00:00 2000-01-04 11:00:00
2     1 2000-01-03 11:00:00 2000-01-04 11:00:00 2000-01-05 11:00:00 2000-01-06 11:00:00
3     1 2000-01-04 11:20:00 2000-01-05 11:20:00 2000-01-06 11:20:00 2000-01-07 11:20:00
4     1 2000-01-04 14:20:00 2000-01-05 14:20:00 2000-01-06 14:20:00 2000-01-07 14:20:00
5     1 2000-01-05 11:40:00 2000-01-06 11:40:00 2000-01-07 11:40:00 2000-01-08 11:40:00
6     2 2000-01-09 12:20:00 2000-01-10 12:20:00 2000-01-11 12:20:00 2000-01-12 12:20:00
7     2 2000-01-09 13:20:00 2000-01-10 13:20:00 2000-01-11 13:20:00 2000-01-12 13:20:00
8     2 2000-01-10 12:20:00 2000-01-11 12:20:00 2000-01-12 12:20:00 2000-01-13 12:20:00
9     2 2000-01-12 16:20:00 2000-01-13 16:20:00 2000-01-14 16:20:00 2000-01-15 16:20:00
```